# How can I tell TeXstudio to delete .bcf, .run.xml, and .synctex.gz?

Tags: texstudio, texworks

TeXstudio's Tool "Clean Auxiliary Files" does not delete .bcf, .run.xml, and .synctex.gz files.

On the other hand, in TexWorks you can edit a configuration file to tell it to delete whatever file extension you want!
How can I do that in TeXstudio?

Answer (score 6):

You can specify the file extensions in the "Clean Auxiliary Files" dialog.

Answer (score 1):

In the "Build" section of the configuration window, you can add a custom command to delete any number of files, which have the same filename as your document and specified extensions. For example under Windows, to delete files `.ext1`, `.ext2` and `.ext3`, you can add the command `clean-files` = `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C del "?am.ext1" "?am.ext2" "?am.ext3"`. You can later refer to this command as `txs:///clean-files` in order to add it to a menu, a toolbar or a sequence for another command.

Answer (score -3):

Put in your default compiler `txs:///latexmk -c`